# Get Feature Count

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, attribute-table, features

My situation is as below,

Database 1 : SDE database.Topo
Feature Class : 170

Database 2 : SDE database.AOI
Feature Class : 1

I want to get feature count of 170 feature classes base on selected AOI in SDE database.AOI.

How to get the total of the features?

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

# Make a layer from the feature class
indexLyr = r"Database Connections\Connection to Metadata5K.sde\MY711T_5K" 
indexLyrSelect = "MY711T5 Selection"
kode = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(indexLyr, indexLyrSelect, '"SHEET_NO" = \'' + kode +'\'')

# Select all feature class that overlap aoi
env.workspace = r"Database Connections\Topo.sde" 
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "fcLyr")
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcLyr, "INTERSECT", indexLyrSelect)        
            arcpy.GetCount_management("fcLyr")
            result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fcLyr).getOutput(0))
            print result
```

Comment: So, you have one or more polygons in the AOI feature class. You want to do the Select By Location (with intersect or within rule) to count the number of features that meet the query in the 170 feature classes (i.e., located within the AOI feature class polygon(s)?

Comment: Use Get Count after Select By Location.  Do it using the AOI and one feature class first, then when that works Copy As Python Snippet it into a Python script and iterate.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Yes, I have modified this script but return error, i dont know what is wrong with the script, how to paste the script here?

Comment: @KhadijahNas, you copy/paste in the question body and then choose the Code markup for that chunk of text. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks